# How to get unique device Id which alway the same when reinstall Xamarin apps

Tags: xamarin, push-notification

I am using Xam.Plugins.DeviceInfo package for the device id but it gave me different id when I reinstall the application. Will I be able to get only one unique Id e.g. A serial number uniquely given for each devices.

I am doing notification hub. If I have a unique id per device not application level, then everytime reinstall the application I don't need to register as a new installation to the notification hub.

Comment: Are you talking about an app update or an app delete / reinstall?

Comment: Check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Comment: Application delete then re-install.. I can see the Id coming from Xaml.Plugin.DeviceInfo is different

Comment: What platform? On iOS this is NOT possible, iOS provides different ids when apps are reinstalled to stop tracking individual devices.

Comment: Both platform... Coz if I know the id, I can use it as a installation id..